# Use '+' instead of %2C' in $_GET query url

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form with a location search input. The search input uses google places autocomplete. I am passing the value of the search input to a hidden field named 'query'. When the form is submitted the value of the hidden field is then appended to the URL as a querystring:

```
<input id="foo" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
<input id="bar" type="hidden" name="query" value="">
```

From the above example, the URL will look like this:

```
http://example.com/?query=ExampleC%2Blocation%2C%2BUS
```

This querystring is only used for analysing analytics. Is there a way to format the URL in a more human-readable way with pluses? So, for example:

```
http://example.com/?query=Example+location,+us
```

In my Javascript file I have tried the following:

```
document.getElementById("bar").value = usersearch.split(' ').join('+');
```

And in my PHP I have added the following for already-performed searches:

```
<input id="bar" type="hidden" name="query" value="<?php echo urlencode($_GET['query']) ?>">
```

Neither seems to work. The URL still ends up with `%2B` etc.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript: [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```
const someEncodedUri = 'http://example.com/?query=ExampleC%2Blocation%2C%2BUS';
console.log(decodeURIComponent(someEncodedUri)); // http://example.com/?query=Example+location,+us
```

PHP: [`urldecode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
$someEncodedUri = 'http://example.com/?query=ExampleC%2Blocation%2C%2BUS';
echo urldecode($someEncodedUri));
```

Do note that if you are actually hitting the URL, you will want to hit it encoded to avoid problems, and then just decode it on the server for analytics purposes.

Answer (score 0):

By default the browser will encodes the URL for special characters for security reason it's a native functionality, You have to collect and decode those special characters at the receiving end